# Propel ORM data fixtures

Tags: database, zend-framework, orm, symfony1, propel

If I have a yml data fixture file called `mydata.yml`

```
User:
  anonymous:
    nickname: anonymous
    first_name: Anonymous

  david:
    nickname: david
    first_name: David
```

How do I tell propel where to find this file. Do I need to add any instructions to the `build.properties`

and how do I run it to insert the data into the database (I've already done `propel-gen insert-sql`, do I need to repeat it or something)

Note: I'm using Propel in a php project not a Symfony project so don't have access to any settings Symfony may have added if any.

Answer (score 3):

You can prepare your inserts in a separate SQL file (for example `fixtures.sql`) and tell the Propel in file `sqldb.map` to run it when processing the `propel-gen insert-sql` command.

Contents of the `sqldb.map` may look like this:

```
# Sqlfile -> Database map
schema.sql=yourdatabasename
fixtures.sql=yourdatabasename
```

The `sqldb.map` file is created in directory specified by `propel.sql.dir` line in `build.properties` file.

In theory you can run Symfony sandbox somewhere and let it convert the fixtures in yml format to SQL commands and then use it with Propel in your project.

Answer (score 2):

Loading data from fixtures is a feature that Symfony adds to Propel, it is not a part of the "core" Propel framework. So if you don't use Symfony, you can't load the data without other code. It might be possible to isolate and strip out the code from [the `sfPropelData` class](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/plugins/sfPropelPlugin/lib/addon/sfPropelData.class.php) that does the actual loading, so you can use it in another framework. Please release your code to the public if you succeed in this, others might like it too!